# How to generate lists of fresh variables in Mercury like I can in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, mercury

In SWI Prolog, `list(Xs) :- length(Xs, _).` is "pure" in that I can pass it a variable with any sort of instantiatedness and it will nondeterministically unify it with all most general unifiers of a particular length.

Is it possible to write a pure `list/1` in Mercury? [The manual seemed to hint this could be done](https://www.mercurylang.org/information/doc-latest/mercury_ref/Insts-modes-and-mode-definitions.html), but I'm having trouble actually implementing it.

What I have so far is:

```
:- module mylist.

:- interface.

:- import_module list.

:- inst frees for list/1
    --->    []
    ;       [free | frees].
:- mode free_to_frees == free >> frees.

:- pred mylist(list(_)).
:- mode mylist(in) is det.
:- mode mylist(free_to_frees) is multi.

:- implementation.

:- pragma promise_pure(mylist/1).

mylist(_::in).

mylist([]::free_to_frees).
mylist([_|Xs]::free_to_frees) :- mylist(Xs).
```

However, when I try this:

```
:- module main.
:- interface.
:- implementation.
:- import_module list, mylist.

:- pred getlist(list(int)).
:- mode getlist(free >> ground) is multi.
getlist(Xs) :- Xs = [1, 2, 3].
getlist(Xs) :- mylist(Xs), Xs = [5].
```

I get the following error:

```
main.m:011: In clause for `getlist(out)':
main.m:011:   mode error in conjunction. The next 2 error messages indicate
main.m:011:   possible causes of this error.
main.m:011:   
main.m:011:   In clause for `getlist(out)':
main.m:011:   mode error in unification of `Xs' and `list.[V_10 | V_16]'.
main.m:011:   Variable `Xs' has instantiatedness
main.m:011:     bound(
main.m:011:       []
main.m:011:     ;
main.m:011:       '[|]'(
main.m:011:         free,
main.m:011:         named inst mylist.listskel,
main.m:011:         which expands to
main.m:011:           bound(
main.m:011:             []
main.m:011:           ;
main.m:011:             '[|]'(
main.m:011:               free,
main.m:011:               named inst mylist.listskel
main.m:011:             )
main.m:011:           )
main.m:011:       )
main.m:011:     ),
main.m:011:   term `list.[V_10 | V_16]' has instantiatedness
main.m:011:   `named inst list.'[|]'(unique(5), free)'.
main.m:011:   
main.m:011:   In clause for `getlist(out)':
main.m:011:   in argument 1 of clause head:
main.m:011:   mode error in unification of `HeadVar__1' and `Xs'.
main.m:011:   Variable `HeadVar__1' has instantiatedness `free',
main.m:011:   variable `Xs' has instantiatedness
main.m:011:     bound(
main.m:011:       []
main.m:011:     ;
main.m:011:       '[|]'(
main.m:011:         free,
main.m:011:         named inst mylist.listskel,
main.m:011:         which expands to
main.m:011:           bound(
main.m:011:             []
main.m:011:           ;
main.m:011:             '[|]'(
main.m:011:               free,
main.m:011:               named inst mylist.listskel
main.m:011:             )
main.m:011:           )
main.m:011:       )
main.m:011:     ).
```

I'm guessing my use of `free` may be incorrect, or else I need to add an additional mode or generalize my `listskel` inst to cover the case of `mylist(Xs), Xs = [5]`.

Basically, how should I write `mylist/1`, so that it can be used in as many modes as possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps you will get lucky and [Zoltan Somogyi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15554596/zoltan-somogyi) will answer.

Comment: If you are reading this and don't know who Zoltan is then please go to the [Mercury website](https://mercurylang.org/) and keep reading until you understand. Then please consider giving Zoltan an up-vote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Due to a limitation in the Mercury implementation, which is
documented in the LIMITATIONS file in the Mercury distribution,
what you ask for cannot be done.

While the design of the Mercury language allows modes that describe
partially instantiated terms such as a list of free variables, such as
the intended output of `mylist(Xs)`, such terms are not useful unless you can
do something with them, such as unify them with `[5]`. Since the Mercury
compiler needs to know the instantiation state of all variables at all
program points, it can allow this *only* if it can keep track of all
unifications between free variables in such terms with other free variables
(whether they occur in such terms or not). This is because if you have
unifications `A = B`, `B = C`, and `C = D`, and then you unify `D` with `5`,
the compiler needs to know that this grounds not just `D`, but `A`, `B` and `C` as well. This is because those unifications have made `A`, `B` and `C` *aliases*
of `D` (i.e. they are other ways to refer to `D`).

When Mercury was first implemented in the mid-1990s, we had a student
working on alias tracking. Unfortunately, what he found was that while
alias tracking is *possible*, it was not *feasible*, in that it switching
on alias tracking usually at least *doubled* the time required to
compile a module. We considered this to be too high a price to pay
for a capability that was just about never used. And even though today,
due to Moore's law, the absolute cost of alias tracking would be much
smaller, the relative tradeoffs haven't really changed, and we now have
a couple of decades experience in working with Mercury in which we have
found so few situations in which support for filling in partially
instantiated data structures would be useful that off the top of my head
I can't remember any of them.

Programming in Mercury is quite different from programming in Prolog.
This is by design. In Mercury, instead of building a partially
instantiated term and then filling it in, you would simply construct
the final term directly. For any programmer interested in program
reliability, this would be the preferred course of action even when
working in Prolog. In real Prolog programs, as opposed to puzzle solvers
or student exercises, leaving part of a term uninstantiated is far more
likely to be an error than not.

Comment: One exception to the last statement is DCGs, where it is/was normal for the output to have a structure mirroring (more or less) the structure of the grammar, and be built-up during the parsing in some unknown order.

Comment: I wonder how feasible it would be to have alias tracking as an optional (maybe per-module) flag. I think one advantage of working with partially instantiated terms is that they enable a rudimentary form of CLP: I can define a list's length and then instantiate the individual entries later on. This can help modularity of implementation.